# Angular animation doesn't work when it toggle to the same router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I have reset the routeReuseStrategy to toggle same router with different params. After setting, the router will change when it encounter something like `foo/1` -> `foo/2`.

But, When I set the router animation rule like `transition('Foo <=> *', [...]`, it wouldn't happen in `Foo to Foo`, the rule actually is `transition('Foo <=> all except Foo', [...]`. So how can I set the correct animation rule to implement `Foo <=> Foo`? So that I can achieve toggle same router with the slide left and right animation. Thanks.